# Why body doesn't hide overflow?

Tags: html, css, overflow

**What I want:** Set the body `width` smaller than viewport and then hide everything outside the body.
(I know I can use a div container and get what I want)

Here is a [very simple example](https://codepen.io/AlanVncs/pen/mdrXjed) (Codepen)
:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}


/*----- Decoration -----*/
body {
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.hidden {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

body::after {
  content: "Container";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
/*-----------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="hidden" >Should be hidden</div>
```

Comment: Why should it? There is no logical reason for the body NOT to show everything within it. If you can use a container *that* can limit what can be shown within it.

Comment: I can't think of a use case for limiting the body at all. Indeed, styling the body except for minor visual tweaks is usually not recommended.

Comment: @Paulie_D, for a quick and dirty page, you can limit the entire page with `max-width` and center with `margin: 0 auto` to prevent giant content sizes. But, I agree, a container is more robust.

Comment: @Paulie_D I believe it should actually do it, and it does, if you specify the overflow already on the html element (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

That's because we need a way to control the overflow of the viewport. CSS will treat the overflow of the body element as the overflow of the viewport, unless you specify it already on the html element (e.g. `html { overflow: auto; }` probably resolves your issue).

Here is the relevant text from [the CSS 2.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html):

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the
> viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
> "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an
> XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the
> 'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport,
> if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value
> when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'. The element
> from which the value is propagated must have a used value for
> 'overflow' of 'visible'.

Comment: Good find. I was trying to find something like this during my search.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clip-path` to do that. You can just add

```
clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
```

to your body. You can see a working snippet below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

.hidden {
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}


/*----- Decoration -----*/
body {
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 80%;
}

.hidden {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

body::after {
  content: "Container";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
/*-----------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="hidden" >Should be hidden</div>
```

**Note:** I added a width of 80% to the body just to show the result in the snippet.

Comment: This is a quirky behavior contrast to my answer. Yours using `clip-path` cuts off the green element on top of the border, whereas mine using `overflow` cuts off the green element inside the border. Makes sense, because clip-path uses the entirety of the element's dimensions, versus the border being added "after" the overflow hiding occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow:hidden` on the `<html>`/root element in addition to what you have on the `body`. I can't seem to find any documentation about this issue, but it's perhaps related to the part of the spec discussing "[special backgrounds](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds)." Fascinating problem!

More discussion: https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/